# Bugzilla status of the day

Tags: bugzilla

I am using Bugzilla version 4.2 . When you use search engine you can check today's status of each bug in chosen product. But it's for today. I am trying to use advanced search to see the same status for different previous days. How can i achieve that? To see the list of tickets and their status for the chosen day from the past?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using version 5.0.2.

You can use the advance search option to achieve this. Please see the picture.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NJdO.png)